# How to display an SQL string that has been constructed by MySQLDB cursor?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I would like to verify for myself how this MySQL string is translated by the cursor:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from elements where id = %s", (element_id))
```

Is there a way to get at the computed SQL string and print it out, preferably before execution? (the latter is not absolutely necessary - I'm just doing this because I'm learning Python and want to make sure my SQL strings are being sanitized)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. As Ferdinand has pointed out, there is a [`MySQLdb/cursors.py`](http://mysql-python.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mysql-python/trunk/MySQLdb/MySQLdb/cursors.py?revision=639&view=markup) containing an `execute()`, which in turn calls `_query()`.

This puts the executed query into `self._executed`.

So you can get it from `cursor._executed`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Haven't started digging into the python functions yet per Ferdinand's answer, but it is good to know where to look.

Comment: But what arguments, do you give to _query? It only takes one besides self.

Comment: @MadsSkjern `_query` get the query to execute, which is the same as `_executed`. But you are not supposed to call it by yourself. The point was about `_execute` here.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL-Python does nothing special, it just encodes each argument to prevent SQL injections and uses the standard Python `%` operator to replace the `%s` placeholders with the encoded arguments.

If you really want to see the result, run the same code as `cursor.execute()` does:

```
from MySQLdb.converters import get_codec

def prepare_sql(cursor, query, args=None):
    if args is not None:
        query = query % tuple(( get_codec(a, cursor.encoders)(db, a) for a in args ))
    return query
```

See the definition of `execute()` starting at line 168 in [`MySQLdb/cursors.py`](http://mysql-python.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mysql-python/trunk/MySQLdb/MySQLdb/cursors.py?revision=639&view=markup).